# Should you check parameters passed into function before passing them, or check them in the function?

Tags: c, parameter-passing

As a good practice, do you think one should verify passed parameters within a function to which the parameters are being passed, or simply make sure the function will always accept correct parameters?

Consider the following code:

```
Matrix * add_matrices(const Matrix * left, const Matrix * right)
{
    assert(left->rowsCount == right->rowsCount
        && left->colsCount == right->colsCount);

    int rowsCount = left->rowsCount;
    int colsCount = left->colsCount;

    Matrix * matOut = create_matrix(rowsCount, colsCount);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i; i < rowsCount; ++i)
    {
        for (j; j < colsCount; ++j)
        {
            matOut->matrix[i][j] = left->matrix[i][j] + right->matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return matOut;
}
```

Do you think I should check the parameters before passing them to the function or after, ie. in the function? What is a better practice or is it programmer dependant?

Comment: I think that this is opinion based. It doesn't really matter where you check it...

Comment: Yes, adding a precondition like you have done is good practice. The caller must make sure that the matrices are of the same size but no extra test is needed if the matrices are created before the call.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom So even though there's 0% probability someone will work on this code after me (it's just a school project), if someone did, would this code be easy to read and understand? Would another programmer understand that in order to use this function the check for correct parameters has to be made outside the function before passing them?

Comment: It really is a design decision. Users of the code might not want to incurr the cost of runtime checks if they can guarantee on their side that the input is correct. Also note that it is quite common for `assert` to be disabled in production.

Comment: @OndřejŠimon It's common knowledge from mathematics that matrix addition is only defined for matrices of the same size, so I don't think any special documentation is needed.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom And in a case where I was modeling a function that would do not so standard operation, would you put the check inside the function or check the parameters before passing?

Comment: @juanchopanza So neither of styles is bad here? Checking it inside or outside is all fine, as long as it's done well?

Comment: Yes, as long as your function is well documented, then the caller can know if it is their responsibility to provide valid input or not. C is full of functions that assume the called passes valid input and yield undefined behaviour otherwise.

Comment: @OndřejŠimon Assuming the presence of a function `new_matrix`, suppose the caller calls your function as `result = add_matrices(new_matrix(10, 10), new_matrix(10, 10))`, what is there to check on the caller's side?

Answer (score 4):

**Inside.** The function can be viewed as an individual component.
Its author is best placed to define any preconditions and check them.
Checking them outside presupposes the caller knows the preconditions which may not be the case.

Also by placing them inside the function you're assured every call is checked.

You should also check any post-conditions before leaving the function.

For example if you have a function called `int assertValid(const Matrix*matrix)` that checks integrity of the object (e.g. the data is not a `NULL` pointer) you could call it on entry to all functions and before returning from functions that modify a `Matrix`.

Consistently use of pre- and post- condition integrity are an enormously effective way of ensuring quality and localising faults.

In practice zealous conformance to this rule usually results in unacceptable performance. The `assert()` macro or a similar conditional compilation construct is a great asset. See `<assert.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if the function is global in scope or local `static`.

1. A global function cannot control what calls it.  Defensive coding will perform validation of the arguments received.  But how much validation to do?

   ```
   int my_abs(int x) {
     assert(x >= -INT_MAX);
     return abs(x);
   }
   ```

The above example, in a debug build, checks to insure the absolute value function will succeed as `abs(INT_MIN)` may be a problem.  Now if this checking should be in production builds is another question.

```
int some_string(char *s) {
   assert(s != NULL);       
   ...
}
```

In `some_string()` the test for NULL-ness may be dropped as function definition may state that `s` *must* be a string.  Even though `NULL` is not a C string, testing for NULL-ness is only 1 of many bad pointers that could be passed which do not point to a string.  So this test has limited validation.

2. With `static` functions, the code is under local control.  Argument validation could occur by the function, the caller, both or neither.  That selection is code dependent.
3. A counter-example exist with user/file input.  Basic data qualification should occur promptly.

   ```
   int GetDriversAge(FILE *inf) {
     int age;
     if (fscanf("%d", &age) != 1) Handle_Error();
     if (age < 16 || age > 122) Handle_Error();
     return age
   }
   ```
4. In OP's example, parameter checking is done by the function, not the caller.  Without the equivalence test, the function can easily fail in mysterious ways.  The cost of this check here is a small fraction of the code's work.  That makes it a *good* check as expensive checks (time, complexity) can cause more trouble than they solve. Note that if the calling code did this test and `add_matrices()` was called from N places, then that checking code is replicated N times in various, perhaps, inconsistent ways.

   ```
   Matrix * add_matrices(const Matrix * left, const Matrix * right) {
     assert(left->rowsCount == right->rowsCount
         && left->colsCount == right->colsCount);
   ```

---

Conclusion: more compelling reasons to check the parameters in the function than in the caller though exceptions exist.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to check the parameters **inside** the function and act accordingly (throw exceptions, return error messages, etc.). I suppose it's the function's job to check whether the passed parameters are of the correct data type and contain valid values.

Comment: And do you think it is mostly programmer dependant, or is there some convention? Objectice programming speaking, I always put all the check inside methods of a specific Class. Considering that fact, I should probably follow the same principles for structural programming as well.

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific convention, but the way I see it it's the calling function's (or method's) responsibility to check any input (parameters) before actually doing what it has to do.

Comment: Consider having a function that does not do type or data range checking and does what it does from the beginning. In such a case, if the caller does not check the input parameters to the calling function, then you will probably be in trouble in case of problematic input parameters.

Comment: So perhaps instead of having the assertion in the place, which would cause my program to crash, I can invert the condition and if the rows and columns of passed matrices do not equal just return NULL. Thank you for the input, Vasilis, I will follow the principles of objective programming int structural from now on, too.

Answer (score 0):

The function should perform its task correctly, otherwise, it should throw an exception. The client/consuming code may or may not do a check, it depends on the data source and how much you trust it, either way, you should also enclose the function call in a catch-try block to catch invalid argument exception.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I confused C for C++. Instead of throwing an exception, you can return null. The client doesn't necessarily have to check the data before calling (depending on the data source and other factors like performance constraints), but must always check for null as a return value.

Comment: I am coding in C, not C++, Matrix is just a simple struct. As far as I know, there are no exceptions in C.

Comment: @OndřejŠimon Apologies, I missed this. You can return null instead. The caller must check for null return value but doesn't have to check the data first (it depends on data source).